# Where are the repo files in a working-directory context?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a repo for a simple file consisting on a `front` directory (TS, Vue.js, Quasar) and a `back` one. The skeleton of the project is

```
infinote/
├─ front/
│  ├─ package.json
│  ├─ src/
├─ back/
├─ .git/
```

I am trying to build the front through the following job:

```
jobs:
  front:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      working-directory: ./front
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: master
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '14'
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm install -g @quasar/cli
      - run: quasar build
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: front
          path: dist/spa
```

This fails because `npm install` cannot find anything to install:

```
Run npm install
  npm install
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    working-directory: ./front
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/work/infinote/infinote/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/work/infinote/infinote/package.json'
npm WARN infinote No description
npm WARN infinote No repository field.
npm WARN infinote No README data
npm WARN infinote No license field.

up to date in 0.24s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

**I suppose that this is because `package.json` (and the rest of the project) is somewhere else. Where should I expect to find it?**

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve (*to use a working-directory for an entire job*) can be done by using `${{env.working-directory}}` with the `run: npm install` command, as explained in this [github community answer](https://github.community/t/use-working-directory-for-entire-job/16747/2).

Without informing the `working-directory` with the step, the command will be executed *at the repository root* (where there is no `package.json` file). More information about this syntax can be found [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun).

Your workflow should look like this:

```yaml
jobs:
  front:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      working-directory: ./front
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: master
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '14'
      - run: npm install
        working-directory: ${{env.working-directory}}
      - run: npm install -g @quasar/cli
        working-directory: ${{env.working-directory}}
      - run: quasar build
        working-directory: ${{env.working-directory}} #not sure if this one is necessary
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: front
          path: dist/spa
```

Answer (score 0):

The working directory should be set for the whole job via an entry in `defaults`:

```
jobs:
  front:
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./front
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: master
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '14'
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm install -g @quasar/cli
      - run: quasar build
      - run: ls -lR dist
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: front
          path: ./dist/spa/
```